# LINQ FirstOrDefault test for null

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

`Word1252_7bit` is a struct
`Key` is `Int32`

How can I test for null if value is not found?

There is no w.Key == -1 but I don't know test for not value returned.

The last Debug line throws an exception.

```
List<Word1252_7bit> Words7bit = GetWord1252_7bit();

Word1252_7bit word1252_7bit ;

word1252_7bit = Words7bit.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Key == 1000);
Debug.WriteLine(word1252_7bit.Key.ToString() + " " + word1252_7bit.Value);

word1252_7bit = Words7bit.FirstOrDefault(w => w.Key == -1);
//if (word1252_7bit == null) Debug.WriteLine("word1252_7bit == null");
Debug.WriteLine( word1252_7bit.Key.ToString() + " " + word1252_7bit.Value ) ;
```

If I should use something other than FirstOrDefault let me know. Looking for speed searching on a unique Int32.

Not sure if it makes a difference but Key is unique and I use Key to override GetHashCode(), And to save space Key is really a piece of an UInt32

```
public Int32 Key
{
  get
  {
    return (Int32)( pack[0] & ( (1<<25) - 1 ) ) ;
  }
}

public struct Word1252_7bit : iWord
{
    // this maps 128 values to "Windows-1252" 
    // this is not ASCII 
    // this is SQL char 8bit normalized to FormD, remove control chars, remove redactions, and cast to lower - 129 - just have to cheat on 1
    private static byte[] Win1252_128to256 = new byte[] {  
             32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63
           , 64, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121
           ,122,123,124,125,126,128,130,131,132,133,134,135,137,139,145,146,147,148,149,150,151,152,153,155,156,160,161,162,163,164,165,166
           ,167,168,169,170,171,172,173,174,175,176,177,178,179,180,181,182,183,184,185,186,187,188,189,190,191,215,223,230,240,247,248,254 };
    private static Encoding win1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
    private UInt32[] pack;
    public Int32 Key { get { return (Int32)(pack[0] & ((1 << 25) - 1)); } }
    public override bool Equals(Object obj)
    {
        // Check for null values and compare run-time types.
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!(obj is Word1252_7bit)) return false;
        Word1252_7bit comp = (Word1252_7bit)obj;
        if (comp.pack == null) return false;
        if (comp.pack.Count() == 0) return false;
        return (comp.Key == this.Key);
    }
    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Key;
    }
    public byte[] Bytes
    {
        get
        {
            byte b;              
            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>(((pack.Length - 1) * 4) + 1);

            b = (byte)((pack[0] >> 25) & ((1 << 7) - 1));
            bytes.Add(Win1252_128to256[b]);

            if (pack.Length > 1)
            {                       
                UInt32 cur32;
                byte bits4 = 0;
                byte bits3 = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < pack.Length; i++)
                {
                    cur32 = pack[i];

                    if ((i-1) % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        bits4 = (byte)((cur32 >> 28) & ((1 << 4) - 1));
                    }
                    else
                    {   // pick up that odd i7
                        bits3 = (Byte)((cur32 >> 28) & ((1 << 3) - 1));
                        b = (byte)((UInt32)bits3 | ((UInt32)bits4 << 3));
                        if (b == 0) break;
                        bytes.Add(Win1252_128to256[b]);
                    }

                    b = (byte)(cur32         & ((1 << 7) - 1));
                    if (b == 0) break;
                    bytes.Add(Win1252_128to256[b]);

                    b = (byte)((cur32 >>  7) & ((1 << 7) - 1));
                    if (b == 0) break;
                    bytes.Add(Win1252_128to256[b]);

                    b = (byte)((cur32 >> 14) & ((1 << 7) - 1));
                    if (b == 0) break;
                    bytes.Add(Win1252_128to256[b]);

                    b = (byte)((cur32 >> 21) & ((1 << 7) - 1));
                    if (b == 0) break;
                    bytes.Add(Win1252_128to256[b]);

                    //Debug.WriteLine(win1252.GetString(bytes.ToArray()));   
                }
            }
            return bytes.ToArray();
        }
    }
    public String Value
    {
        get
        {
            return win1252.GetString(Bytes);
        }
    }
    public Int32 Lenght { get { return Bytes.Count(); } }
    public Word1252_7bit(UInt32[] Pack)
    {
        if(Pack == null) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        if (Pack.Length == 0) throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
        pack = Pack;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you've got an array within a value type, which is rarely a good idea. It's unclear what the bigger picture is here - but perhaps you just want a dictionary?

Comment: @JonSkeet Why is an array in a value type a bad idea?  Maybe I am going the wrong direction but I am headed away from Dictionary < Int32, string > .  I have a very large list of words and getting out of memory exceptions.  My chars are only 7 bit so I am packing 4.5 7bit chars in a UInt32.   The Key only needs to be 27 bits so using the last 7 from that UInt32 for the first char.

Comment: For one thing, you're wasting space by creating an array at all. For another, creating `new Word1252_7bit()` will always have a null reference in the array, which is probably undesirable. It's unclear what your struct looks like, but I suspect it could be cleaner. If you want to have a small struct for just the word, that's fine - but then you could have a `Dictionary<int, ShortWord>`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Happy to have you critique the full posted struct.  How is that array a waste?  Dictionary uses a full int32 for the key and I don't need the full int.  I am able to steal 1 7bit char from the Key. I pass the minimum size array needed based on the number of characters in the word.

Comment: Ah, I had thought that you were using a fixed (small) size of array. Does saving these few bits *really* justify the complexity here? I dare say the simplest possible code is too big - but I bet there are simpler ways which are still cheap enough.

Comment: @JonSkeet  But, there is no "cheap enough".  The design objective was as cheap as possible.  As stated was getting out of memory exception with Dictionary < Int, String >.  Not just few bits - half the number of bits.  Even with doubling the List size there are some data sets we will still need to break up.

Comment: There's *always* a cheap enough. Do you think it is absolutely impossible to get this any cheaper, however hard you try? For example, if your words *tend* to be ASCII-heavy I suspect you could come up with a custom compression scheme which would reduce the overall space... but it would be even *more* complex. Suppose you just stored the "raw" byte array... you'd still save half the space vs `string`, but with much less complexity. What about a `Dictionary<int, byte[]>` (quite possibly encapsulated)?

Comment: @JonSkeet That code already has a custom compression that takes Win1252 to 7 bit by ignoring control chars, removing diatricss, and casting to lower.  Tried Dictionary < int, byte[] > and was it was not efficient.  I did not do this for the fun of it.

Comment: My point is that just because you've done some compression doesn't mean it would be impossible to do more. At some point you need to stop. "Not efficient" is always relative - yes, a `Dictionary<int, byte[]>` would be slightly less space-efficient - but it would avoid an O(N) lookup time...

Comment: @JonSkeet  Since the question is about how to perform a lookup your point on 0(N) is valid.  This really is a case of will take O(N) for a 7 bits as rarely need a lookup.  And I did stop at 7 bits.  Since I was already removing diatrics and SQL is using a case insensitive search I got down to 7 bits with no loss of clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault<T>` will return the first item found or the default value of `T` if none is found. For reference types this is `null`, but this is different for value types. For example, the default value of integers is `0`.

You can use the [`default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) keyword:

```
if (word1252_7bit.Equals(default(Word1252_7bit)))
    Debug.WriteLine("not found");
```

<sup>*NOTE: You may have to write you're own override of [`Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dts52z7.aspx) to get the result you expect.*</sup>

In general, you won't be able to distinguish an item that was not found from an item that was found but which is equal to the default value. You can do this instead:

```
int foundAt = Words7bit.FindIndex(w => w.Key == -1);
if (foundAt == -1)
    Debug.WriteLine("not found");
else
    word1252_7bit = Words7bit[foundAt];
```

Comment: Get an error Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Word1252_7bit' and 'Word1252_7bit'

Comment: Once I fixed a bug in my override Equals the .Equals worked.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To have some more control you could define your own `Default` value, e.g. using something like:

```
public static T FirstOrDefault<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, T defaultValue)
{
    foreach (var element in sequence)
        return element;
    return defaultValue; // default(T);
    // return sequence.Any() ? sequence.First() : defaultValue;
}
```

Then use it like

```
word1252_7bit = Words7bit.Where(w => w.Key == 1000)
    .FirstOrDefault(Word1252_7bit.Default);
```

where 'Default' is a default instance defined for your struct. Something like...

```
public static readonly Word1252_7bit Default = new Word1252_7bit 
{ 
    Key = Int32.MinValue,
    Value = "default",
};
```

**EDIT:** Improved `FirstOrDefault` code (based on the original implementation)

Comment: I thought about using Any First directly.  But my concern is that two searches (if Any is true).

Comment: @Blam - actually I just made that fast - I'll dig the original code for it - so I'm guessing just adjusting it then to support the default - and you'll get the performant solution if that's what you're worried about. Most of the time this is more than acceptable I think. I'll update that later on you if you need it, let me know.

Comment: Since I am generating a perfect hash is there some way to take advantage of that.  It does not have to be a List.  It just needs enumerable so is can be bound to UI repeater and a search on the key.  The design objective is memory and a KeyedCollection did not appear to be memory efficient but have not given up on it.

Comment: I edited in the `improved FirstOrDefault` (based on the original implementation - it's actually dead simple of course:). So you won't be losing any of the performance. I'll take a look at what you just said when I get off work later on. If you can post some more details (edit question - or possibly this sounds like another one - just @ me here).